# Cannot import large files through browser using JSF (might not be related to the use of JSF)

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, file-upload

I'm currently working on a project where I'm importing a CSV file through a browser, and the data contained in this file are then transfered into a database.

The code I wrote works fine for small files, but it turns out the application does not work with large file (over 200MB).

import.xhtml:

```
...
<t:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="table_layout center" columnClasses="col_label,col_input">
    <t:outputLabel for="importFile" styleClass="required" value="#{messages.import_file}" />
    <t:inputFileUpload id="importFile" value="#{imports.csv}" required="true" />

    <t:panelGroup colspan="2" styleClass="center">
        <t:commandButton action="#{imports.import}" value="#{messages.import_action_import}" disabled="#{imports.state}" reRender="pnl" />
    </t:panelGroup>
</t:panelGrid>
...
```

ImportBean.java

```
public String import() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Entering import()");

            ...
            if (csv != null) {
                fileInputStream = csv.getInputStream();
            }
            final InputStream fileInputStreamF = fileInputStream;

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Entering run()");
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Before entering importService.import(InputStream)");
                        importService.import(fileInputStreamF);
                    } catch (MyException e) {
                        ...
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            };
            System.out.println("Before running Thread");
            Thread thread = new Thread(r);
}
```

So when I'm trying to upload a small file, the console shows:

```
Entering import()
Before running Thread
Entering run()
Before entering importService.import(InputStream)
```

But when I try to upload a large file, the console shows absolutely nothing, which means (I believe) that `ImportBean.import()` is not being called.

For this project, I'm using Java 5, JSF 1.1 and Tomcat 5.
My guess is that there is something I should configure in Tomcat, but I'm not sure about it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I tried to set `maxPostSize` to 0 in Tomcat server.xml, but it doesn't seem to do anything.
I've just used a packet analyzer (Wireshark) and it seems that the file is being uploaded for about a minute then stops. And when it stops, there is still nothing on the console...

Comment: Maybe there's a max file size configuration. If so, then you just have to change that value for 209715200 (200 MB).

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the `max-file-size` and `max-request-size` in `web.xml`.
Restart tomcat, and deploy the WAR file again.

Answer (score 0):

If the max-file-size and max-request-size doesn't work, the issue might be the transfer takes too long and exceeds the browsers time-out.

I worked on a similar issue using struts, and the only way to resolve it was to have the client transfer the csv in a zip file, we then unzipped and processed the file.

Our import function also took awhile to process the file so we had to forward the user to a refresh page that periodically checked the status of the import.